# Can´t deploy my azure function app with cli or .NET

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a functions app running Azure functions V2 with .NET Core 2.1.

My problem is that i can´t deploy my application, neither using the cli or the 'publish' option inside .Net. 
This is my error code when trying to deploy with cli:

> Getting site publishing info...
>   Publish (**myapp**) contents to an Azure Function App. Locally deleted files are not removed from destination.
>   Creating archive for current directory...
>   Uploading archive...
>   Error uploading archive (InternalServerError).
>   Retry: 1 of 2
>   Creating archive for current directory...
>   Uploading archive...
>   Error uploading archive (InternalServerError).
>   Retry: 2 of 2
>   Creating archive for current directory...
>   Uploading archive...
>   Error uploading archive (InternalServerError).

When i try publish with .Net i get "Publishing failed". 
I have been googling around for days trying to solve this problem with no success. Can´t even remember all the ways iv been trying to be able to solve this...

Deleting functions in the portal or node_modules folders as mentioned [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/352)
is something i rather not do since the code is pretty much in production.

Im just stuck and i cant find any way to solve this.

If anyone could take the time to help me it would be highly appreciated, i just want to code :(

Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve the problem with latest v2 cli?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue a couple of times. In my case the Azure Function process keeps a lock on some of the DLL's in the bin directory, even restarting the azure app has failed to release the lock. The only fix I have found is to delete the function and re-deploy.

Can you not deploy to a new function and swap over the production environment to the new function and then remove the old faulted one?

Answer (score 0):

Your Cli is probably outdated or the version mismatches, try the [latest v2 Cli](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools#installing). It publishes function project using [run from package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package), which makes us free from locking dlls error.

It shows process as below.

```
Getting site publishing info...
Preparing archive...
Uploading xxx MB [###############################################################################]
Upload completed successfully.
Deployment completed successfully.
Syncing triggers...
```